# Creating class-wide(global) accessible object

Tags: php

Is it possible to declare an object and have that object available throughout the class?

Example of what I'm trying, below does not work:

```
Class food{
     private $need;

     public function __construct()
     {
        $this->$need = new Something();
     }

     public function some_function()
     {
        $this->$need->some_method();
     }
}
```

Each attempts end with `$need` being a null value.
Feel like I'm missing something very basic here...

PHP version is 5.3

MORE information

```
`$need = new Something($this->method) // this object has a callback `
```

Could this have something to do with it ?

Comment: There is no point fixing your question to match the answer given as it makes the answer look like nonsence. **Dont do it**

Comment: You misunderstand. It was a typo, even with `$this` I still have a problem. If his answer solved my problem, I would mark it as so.

Comment: **It almost always helps if you give the complete question to start with and do not add new information with every failed attempt people make to answer it.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question keeps changing with every attempt people make to answer it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by passing as string for the callback url vs `$this->method`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `$this`, which is used to refer to the instance of the class you're working with

```
Class food{
     private $need;

     public function __construct()
     {
        $this->need = new Something();
     }

     public function some_function()
     {
        $this->need->some_method();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works so where is the difference between this code and yours? I assume you have actually declared the `Something` class or at least included it in your code?

```
Class Something
{

     public function __construct()
     {
        echo 'Something() got constructed'.PHP_EOL;
     }

    public function some_method()
    {
        echo 'Something().some_method() got run'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}


Class food{
     private $need;

     public function __construct()
     {
        $this->need = new Something();
     }

     public function some_function()
     {
        $this->need->some_method();
     }
}


$o = new food();
$o->some_function();
```